# My regexp not working correct how to change this?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a little string:

```
JIW.sql;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;saasa.sql;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;aas.sql
```

and i need make select with like this

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('JIW.sql;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;saasa.sql;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;aas.sql', '[0-9A-z]*.sql');
```

And i would like expect:

```
JIW.sql
saasa.sql
lok.SQL
aas.sql
```

but now i have

```
---------------------------

;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;
;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;

(4 rows)
```

How to change this ?

Comment: Try `[^.]+.sql` as your regex

Comment: now is  _;XXX.txt;Qwij._
 _;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd._

Comment: The 2nd parameter is what is used to to the split, so your query is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('JIW.sql;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;saasa.sql;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;aas.sql', '[0-9A-z]*.sql', 'g');
```

instead ie. **regexp_matches** instead of **regexp_split_to_table**

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `regexp_split_to_table` function, which **splits** your string when it matches the pattern.

You'd use `regex_matches` to find matches for your regex pattern:

```
SELECT 
  regexp_matches(
    'JIW.sql;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;saasa.sql;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;aas.sql',
    E'([^;]+\.sql)',
    'gi'
  );
```

Where, the `gi` parameter are the modifiers for **global** and **case-insensitive** search. The result would be something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2136).

You can also use the `unnest` function to get the [result returned as rows instead](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2139). The query would then be:

```
SELECT 
  unnest(
    regexp_matches(
      'JIW.sql;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;saasa.sql;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;aas.sql',
      E'([^;]+\.sql)',
      'gi'
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `regexp_split_to_table`, but based on a quick Google search (and the name of the operation) I guess that the pattern you give to it is the delimiter pattern. In other words, what is returned will be the values *between* the strings matched by your pattern, and whatever matches the pattern will be removed from the results.

If you gave ';" as a pattern, it would produce

```
JIW.sql
XXX.txt
Qwij.DLL
saasa.sql
ttt.txt
lok.SQL
ddd.jpg
aas.sql
```

I'm not sure a split is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `regexp_split_to_table`, try with:

```
SELECT result.filename FROM
  (SELECT regexp_split_to_table('JIW.sql;XXX.txt;Qwij.DLL;saasa.sql;ttt.txt;lok.SQL;ddd.jpg;aas.sql', ';') AS filename) result
 WHERE result.filename ILIKE '%.sql'
```

Output:

```
"JIW.sql"
"saasa.sql"
"lok.SQL"
"aas.sql"
```